Laravel Bootcamp - 07. Notifications & Events Fail
I'm following the Laravel Bootcamp tutorial on notifications and events, specifically from this section: Laravel Bootcamp - Notifications and Events. I’ve followed all the steps as outlined in the tutorial, but I encounter an error in the last chapter when trying to send a mail notification.
Screenshot
mail-notification-error
I've attempted a solution found on Stack Overflow here: Laravel Bootcamp Send Notification Fails, but unfortunately, the issue persists.
My code is exactly as described in the tutorial, yet it still fails. I’ve uploaded my project repository here if anyone would like to explore the code for more context: GitHub - Chirper Laravel Project.
I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

This may be related to the newer symfony/mailer package, at the time of writing v7.2.0 is not fully supported by Laravel. Downgrade by running: composer require "symfony/mailer:~7.1.0"
The full error in Laravel log files:
local.ERROR: The "" scheme is not supported; supported schemes for mailer "smtp" are: "smtp", "smtps". {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Mailer\\Exception\\UnsupportedSchemeException(code: 0): The \"\" scheme is not supported; supported schemes for mailer \"smtp\" are: \"smtp\", \"smtps\". at ***\\vendor\\symfony\\mailer\\Transport\\Smtp\\EsmtpTransportFactory.php:28)

Ref. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/53721
